# What's the difference between "react-native bundle" and "react-native unbundle"?

Tags: react-native

What is the purpose of "unbundle"?

I find two different options to create React Native offline bundle. There is not much description about this option.

> bundle [options]         builds the javascript bundle for offline use
>
> unbundle [options]       builds javascript as "unbundle" for offline use

I usually create a react-native bundle using "react-native bundle" command like:

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle
```

Even if I create a bundle using command below, I can run it as same as previous one:

```
react-native unbundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle
```

Size of output file is almost same, definitely contents of ouptut file is different. I thought 'unbundle' option is to create multiple separated bundles to share common part of bundle.

Does anyone know exactly what 'unbundle' is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

android unbundle means create separated files.
ios unbundle means create a big file contains mapping table and codes.
It is slow for iOS to load multiple small files.

Comment: Any documents avaiable?